# unable to write the textfile?

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone,i can read the txtfile using this code

```
-(NSString *)readfile:(NSString *)filename{
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainbundle] PathForResource:filename ofType:"txt"];
    NSData *mydata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *str;
    if(mydata){
        str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:mydata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    return str;
 }
```

Method Call::

```
 ownservices *readtxt=[[ownservices alloc] init];
 [readtxt readfile:@"textfile"];
```

By using this code i can read data from txtfile. By using these code i want to write add text to textfile

```
-(NSString *)writefile:(NSString *)filename:(NSString *)text{
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainbundle] PathForResource:filename ofType:"txt"];
    //NSData *mydata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [text writeToFile:path dataUsingEncoding:NSTUF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    return text;
 }
```

Method call:

```
  ownservices *write=[[ownservices alloc] init];
    [write writefile:@"txtfile":@"Hello"];
```

but text is not adding to `txtfile` save in resource folder
anyone have an idea please help me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can not save anything in resource folder at run time. You can save the file in documents folder.

Comment: thanks for your help, but while adding textfile we have to add under resources,i can read data from that file but can't add additional text to that file,please send sample code.

Comment: Google for "how to write file in iOS". resource files are copied in bundle. They are for reading in app, not writing.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the function prototype**

```
-(NSString *) writefile:(NSString *)filename  withText:(NSString *)text;
```

**Definition :**

```
-(NSString *)writefile:(NSString *)filename  withText:(NSString *)text
{
        //Put your code here
}
```

**Calling place:**

```
[write writefile:@"txtfile" withText:@"Hello"];
```

Comment: @sirishagalla not to write in **runtime** **readonly**  **resource** folder and write with document directory as mentioned by @taskinoor in his answer,

Comment: OP is trying to write in resource folder.

Comment: Its not only a suggestion. Its a must. You can NOT write in resource.